# Set value for Model field that is not part of ModelForm?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm which has a subset of fields of the model it is for. When I'm processing that form, checking is_valid etc, I want to check the value of a given field that may have changed, so I check if form.has_changed() and then I check if myfield in form.changed_data. If that is true, I want to set the value for a field on my model, but that field is NOT on this modelform. How might I go about doing that?

I know I can access myform.instance directly, but since I'm already calling myform.save() later on, can I set the value on the form itself somehow, even if that field is not part of the modelform?

Answer (score 1):

Use `commit=False` in `ModelForm.save`, like this:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
if requires_update:
    instance.field_to_change = value_to_set
instance.save()
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid manipulating the instance directly since I am already working with the form and calling form.save later on, so I'm looking for a way to set this field value through the form itself. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There is no way to do it except accessing the form's `instance`, because you are not including that field into the form. If you want to keep things on the form, then add a function to the form to perform that action. But that function will end up accessing the internal instance.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña answer is the way to go, you can save any value on the the model even if it's not added to the form itself. There is most likely other ways of doing the same thing but not really the Django way.